# Adding Row to other sheets

Tags: vba, excel, button, rows

I added a button in sheet1, wrote code for it to add rows in sheet1, succeeded.

But I want the button to keep in sheet1 but rows to be added in sheet2.
Simply copying code from sheet1 to sheet2 doesn't work.

What do I need to do?

Button is in sheet 1, this code is in sheet1 but I want work done to be in sheet2.

The code:

```
Private sub cmdbtn1_click
Dim rn as variant   'rn =row number
Dim x as variant.   
x=sheet2.cells(1,1) 'it has serial no. of last row
on error resume next
rn=x+4.    ' i want to add row after 4 lines of sr.no.
sheet2.rows(rn+1 & ":" & rn+1).insert shift:=xlup
sheet2.rows(rn & ":" & rn).copyrange("A" & rn)
sheet2.range(rn+1 & ":" & rn+1).clearcontents
sheet2.cells(rn+1,1)=x+1
endsub
```

This code is not adding rows to sheet2 yet because code of one sheet is not accessible by another.

Comment: Without the relevant code, it is going to be very hard to determine what needs to be changed to make it work, so please edit your question and paste your code into it.  (It could be as simple as changing `"Sheet1"` to `"Sheet2"`, but we can't tell without the code.)

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24064090/1270789) might help. As mentioned above, you need to post your code before anyone can give proper assistance.

Comment: where are you setting your sheet2 variable? `Set sheet2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2")`